# What's the difference between WordPress multisite and multiple installs(virtual hosts)?

Tags: wordpress, apache, multisite

So I have two blogs running on my one VPS. Both are `WordPress`,and I use separate folders and databases for each by using separate `apache` virtual hose config files.

What is the difference between this, and a WordPress multisite install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress Multisite can share plugins between sites, as well as users (with the right configuration). It also uses a single database with different prefixes for each site.

Comment: Is there an advantage to that?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. I have used a multisite with shared users/plugins and different themes for a business. You can let users control a single blog (site) without giving them super admin access to control plugins available site-wide. You can enable plugins for every site from the network admin. So on and so forth.